# How to add colours to different areas

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

So I created a recurring pattern using two different designs. The problem now is making the colours, so I have to ask the user to pick 3 different colours and use them to make certain areas of the designs that colour. For example what I mean is, if I were to choose the 5x5 patch layout then the first 2 boxes of patterns across and below should be one colour (so that's four boxes) and so on.

EDIT: to clear up the confusion.

1. So if you look at the 500x500 one. type '5' when it asks for what patch size you want.
2. you should see two different pattern designs.
3. all I want is the x = 0 to x = 200 and y = 0 to y = 200 to be blue colour. Meaning that everything in that area (by area, I mean all the pattern designs that are in there) should be a blue colour. The same colour should be used for x = 300 to x = 500 and y = 300 to y = 500.
4. the x = 300 to x = 500 and y = 0 to y = 200 should be red colour and the x = 0 to x = 200 and y = 300 to y = 500 should also be red.
5. and all that is left is the '+' part in the middle which should have the third colour, green.
6. https://prntscr.com/m48xxd this is what I mean by the colours. so the top left and bottom right are the same colours. the top right and bottom left are te same colours and the '+' is another colour.

[image: 5x5 patchwork image]

7.https://prntscr.com/m48xzm here is the 7x7 version

[image: 7x7 patchwork image]

I just put colours, for now, to make it easier to look at.

I have already tried doing the 'getX' and 'getY' but I can't seem to get it right.

```
from graphics import *

def main():
    global patchWorkSize
    patchWorkSize = int(input("What patchwork size would you like?"))

    if patchWorkSize == 5:
        patchWork5()
    elif patchWorkSize == 7:
        patchWork7()
    elif patchWorkSize == 9:
        patchWork9()
    else:
        print('Only patchwork sizes 5, 7 and 9 are avaliable')




def patchWork5():
    layout()

    for y in range(0,500,100):

        for x in range(0,500,200):

            for l1 in range(0,100,20):
                line = Line(Point(l1+x,0+y), Point(100+x,100-l1+y))
                line.draw(win)
            for l2 in range(100,0,-20):
                line3 = Line(Point(l2+x,100+y), Point(0+x,100-l2+y))
                line3.draw(win)

            for l3 in range(100,0,-20):
                line2 = Line(Point(100+x,0+l3+y), Point(0+l3+x,100+y))
                line2.setFill('red')
                line2.draw(win)
            for l4 in range(0,100,20):
                line4 = Line(Point(0+x,100-l4+y), Point(100-l4+x,0+y))
                line4.setFill('red')
                line4.draw(win)

    for e in range(0,500,100):
        for t in range(100,500,200):
            for o in range(0,500,10):
                for c in range(5,100,10):
                    circle1 = Circle(Point(c+t,5+o+e), 5)
                    circle1.setFill('blue')
                    circle1.draw(win)


def patchWork7():
    layout()

    for y in range(0,700,100):

        for x in range(0,700,200):

            for l1 in range(0,100,20):
                line = Line(Point(l1+x,0+y), Point(100+x,100-l1+y))
                line.draw(win)
            for l2 in range(100,0,-20):
                line3 = Line(Point(l2+x,100+y), Point(0+x,100-l2+y))
                line3.draw(win)

            for l3 in range(100,0,-20):
                line2 = Line(Point(100+x,0+l3+y), Point(0+l3+x,100+y))
                line2.setFill('red')
                line2.draw(win)
            for l4 in range(0,100,20):
                line4 = Line(Point(0+x,100-l4+y), Point(100-l4+x,0+y))
                line4.setFill('red')
                line4.draw(win)

    for e in range(0,700,100):
        for t in range(100,700,200):
            for o in range(0,700,10):
                for c in range(5,100,10):
                    circle1 = Circle(Point(c+t,5+o+e), 5)
                    circle1.setFill('blue')
                    circle1.draw(win)

def patchWork9():
    layout()

    for y in range(0,900,100):

        for x in range(0,900,200):

            for l1 in range(0,100,20):
                line = Line(Point(l1+x,0+y), Point(100+x,100-l1+y))
                line.draw(win)
            for l2 in range(100,0,-20):
                line3 = Line(Point(l2+x,100+y), Point(0+x,100-l2+y))
                line3.draw(win)

            for l3 in range(100,0,-20):
                line2 = Line(Point(100+x,0+l3+y), Point(0+l3+x,100+y))
                line2.setFill('red')
                line2.draw(win)
            for l4 in range(0,100,20):
                line4 = Line(Point(0+x,100-l4+y), Point(100-l4+x,0+y))
                line4.setFill('red')
                line4.draw(win)

    for e in range(0,900,100):
        for t in range(100,900,200):
            for o in range(0,900,10):
                for c in range(5,100,10):
                    circle1 = Circle(Point(c+t,5+o+e), 5)
                    circle1.setFill('blue')
                    circle1.draw(win)

def layout():
    global win

    win = GraphWin('Patchwork',patchWorkSize*100, patchWorkSize*100)
    for i in range(0, patchWorkSize*100,100):
        line = Line(Point(i,0), Point(i, patchWorkSize*100))
        line2 = Line(Point(0,i), Point(patchWorkSize*100, i))


        line.draw(win)
        line2.draw(win)

main()
```

Comment: Can you make your question a bit clearer please? It's difficult to know exactly what you are asking.

Comment: The `graphics` tag is not applicable here, you are using the [`graphics` module](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/handsonPythonTutorial/graphics.html) from the [Zelle Python intro course](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/)

Comment: @DanielScott so if you run my code and type '5'. It should display 3 line patterns and 2 circle patterns. (ignore the colours that I have set for now). so from x =0 to x=200 and y=0 to y=200. Those design should be one colour and then the x=300 to x=500 and y =300 to y= 500 should be another colour.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh sorry I didn't know I changed it.

Comment: You need to be much more specific than just saying "...and so on". What exactly should happen in all boxes across and down in the WxW case? You code also appears to be drawing many boxes that aren't visible in the window, for example the 5x5 case is actually drawing 45 boxes—is that your intention?

Comment: @martineau it should be only 25 boxes I don't know why there are 45.

Comment: @martineau can you check my edit to see if it makes more sense what I am trying to ask?

Comment: @martineau nvm I fixed the 45 boxes problem

Comment: Well, that's an improvement—however it sounds like you want to alternate between two colors...so why do you ask the user for 3 of them? It would also be very useful if you showed how the colors are going to be used to draw the `Line`s within at least one of the `patchWorkX()` functions. I know that sounds nit-picky, but it seems like you want to know very specifically how to do it. BTW: a common way to alternate between two things is to count them and test the current value (i.e. checking if it's even would be `if count%2 == 0:`, and checking for odd is simply: `if count%2:`).

Comment: @martineau https://prntscr.com/m48xxd this picture is what I mean. so the boxes with 'F' are the line pattern and the one with nothing are the circles.

Comment: @martineau https://prntscr.com/m48xzm and this is what it should be for the 7x7 one

Comment: OK. That pattern looks like they're all one color until the middle one is reached, then it's drawn in the third color, then the remaining ones are drawn in the other color that hasn't been used yet—sound about right? If it is, please [edit] and add something like that to your question. You can should probably include those image links in it-like they say, a picture's worth a thousand words.

Comment: @martineau yes the top left and bottom right are the same colour. the top right and bottom left are the same colour.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to paramertize *everything* into cubes of a convenient size, and then turn the filling code into subroutines that can be called to fill those cubes.  Below is a rework of your code along these lines that can handle any odd number 3 or greater as an input:

```
from graphics import *

UNIT = 100

def patchWork(win, size):
    blocks = size // 2

    def hatch_box(x, y):
        for n in range(0, UNIT, UNIT//5):
            line = Line(Point(n + x * UNIT, y * UNIT), Point((x + 1) * UNIT, UNIT - n + y * UNIT))
            line.draw(win)

        for n in range(UNIT, 0, -UNIT//5):
            line = Line(Point(n + x * UNIT, (y + 1) * UNIT), Point(x * UNIT, UNIT - n + y * UNIT))
            line.draw(win)

        for n in range(UNIT, 0, -UNIT//5):
            line = Line(Point((x + 1) * UNIT, n + y * UNIT), Point(n + x * UNIT, (y + 1) * UNIT))
            line.setFill('red')
            line.draw(win)

        for n in range(0, UNIT, UNIT//5):
            line = Line(Point(x * UNIT, UNIT - n + y * UNIT), Point(UNIT - n + x * UNIT, y * UNIT))
            line.setFill('red')
            line.draw(win)

    for y in range(blocks):
        for x in range(blocks):
            hatch_box(x, y)

    for y in range(blocks + 1, 2 * blocks + 1):
        for x in range(blocks + 1, 2 * blocks + 1):
            hatch_box(x, y)

    def draw_circles(x, y):
        for o in range(0, UNIT, UNIT // 10):
            for c in range(0, UNIT, UNIT // 10):
                circle = Circle(Point(c + UNIT // 20 + x * UNIT, o + UNIT // 20 + y * UNIT), UNIT // 20)
                circle.setFill('blue')
                circle.draw(win)

    for y in range(blocks):
        for x in range(blocks + 1, 2 * blocks + 1):
            draw_circles(x, y)
            draw_circles(y, x)

    def draw_cube(x, y):
        cube = Rectangle(Point(x * UNIT, y * UNIT), Point((x + 1) * UNIT, (y + 1) * UNIT))
        cube.setFill('yellow')
        cube.draw(win)

    x = blocks
    for y in range(0, 2 * blocks + 1):
        draw_cube(x, y)
        draw_cube(y, x)

def layout(size):
    win = GraphWin('Patchwork', size * UNIT, size * UNIT)

    for i in range(0, size * UNIT, UNIT):
        Line(Point(i, 0), Point(i, size * UNIT)).draw(win)
        Line(Point(0, i), Point(size * UNIT, i)).draw(win)

    return win

def main():
    patchWorkSize = int(input("What patchwork size would you like? "))

    if patchWorkSize % 2 == 1 and patchWorkSize > 2:
        win = layout(patchWorkSize)

        patchWork(win, patchWorkSize)

        win.getMouse() # pause for click in window
        win.close()
    else:
        print('Only odd sizes 3 or greater are available')

main()
```

You should be able to change `UNIT`, within reason.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to write everything for you, but the code below shows how to choose the color for each area based on its position within the patchwork grid (`i` and `j`). The color is determined in `color_func()`.

Hopefully this will be enough for you to figure out how to apply the relatively simple coding pattern shown to draw the desired graphics.

Hint: Compute the coordinates of each graphics element based on (or relative to) these same position values (i.e. don't write a separate function for every possible patchwork size).

This code still seems overly repetitive to me, and could probably be made more concise, but I'll leave that to you, too... `;¬)`

```
def main():
#    size = int(input("What patchwork size would you like?"))
#    Hardcoded for testing.
#
#    if size % 2 == 0:
#        raise RuntimeError('patchwork size must be odd')

    patch_work(5)
    print()
    patch_work(7)

def patch_work(n):
    colors = '0', '1', '2'
    mid = n // 2

    # Call color_func() for every possible position in patchwork and
    # prints the results in rows.
    for i in range(n):
        row = []
        for j in range(n):
            row.append(color_func(n, i, j, colors))
        print(''.join(row))

def color_func(n, i, j, colors):
    mid = n // 2

    if i == mid:
        index = 2

    elif i < mid:
        if j < mid:
            index = 0
        elif j == mid:
            index = 2
        elif j > mid:
            index = 1

    elif i > mid:
        if j < mid:
            index = 1
        elif j == mid:
            index = 2
        elif j > mid:
            index = 0

    return colors[index]


if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Output:

```
00211
00211
22222
11200
11200

0002111
0002111
0002111
2222222
1112000
1112000
1112000
```